How to Return the First Result From A List Based on a Range of Numbers
I'm not sure if the title makes sense, but I hope it does.
Here is what I am trying  to accomplish:
I have a table that looks like the following:



Minimum
Maximum
Category




1
11
11U


1
13
13U


14
15
14-15


16
17
16-17


18
20
JR


15
34
SR


35
39
35


40
44
40


45
49
45



Given an age, for example, 8, I would like the result to be the category 11U. If the given age is 16, then the returned category should be 16-17, not SR. So, always return the first result that matches the given criteria.
Again, I hope that I have explained this well enough. I am more than happy to add more information as needed.
Thanks

This does the trick for me, with your given data set:
=XLOOKUP(1, BITAND(D1>=$A$2:$A$9 , D1<=$B$2:$B$9) , $C$2:$C$9 , "")

Where D1 is the cell containing the value you want to look up.
You can change the "" with "text" or just a number, whatever floats your boat (it's the 'if not found' expression, should the lookup fail).
